# winamp: Please suggest a skin with big buttons and ideally big equalizer

Tags: winamp

Does anybody knows good skin with bug buttons for touch screens.

Ideally I also want big equalizer so I can control pitch and speed!

Comment: I personally like using the Nightvision skin in Modern mode. Pretty big.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few options:

- [Shield Amp](http://www.winamp.com/skin/shield-amp/155686)
- [Nitrous Audio CTI2](http://www.winamp.com/skin/nitrous-audio-cti2/221676)
- [Alpha Media Player X5](http://www.winamp.com/skin/alpha-media-player-x5/221912)
- [Anunaki](http://www.allwinampskins.com/winamp_skin.anunaki.html)